# Does read function affect the get pointer of a file?

Tags: c++

I've got this section of a program that reads data from a .txt file. Here's the code:

```
ifstream inputFile( "C:\\Users ...", ios::in | ios::binary );

    anyClass object;

    inputFile.read( reinterpret_cast< char * >( &object )
                                  , sizeof( anyClass ) );

    while( !inputFile.eof() ) 
    {
        // Reads every object data of the file
        inputFile.read( reinterpret_cast< char * >( &object )
                                 , sizeof( anyClass ) ); 
    }
```

My question is:

- How does the read function reads all the data? Is it making the get pointer of the file move forward?

Comment: There is a *pointer* to the next location to read in a file.  When you open a file this pointer is set to the beginning.  When you read from the file, the pointer advances.  You can change the location of this pointer by using `seekg` method of the stream.  The pointer is always pointing to the next read location (unless its at the end of the file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input file stream maintains the position of the next read location.  This position is advanced for each read transaction (unless there is an error or at end of the file).  The read position may be changed using the `seekg` method.

This can be illustrated by reading any text file:

```
char c;
while (text_file.read(&c, 1))
{
    std::cout << c << "    " << text_file.tellg() << "\n";
}
```

The `tellg` method returns the *read* position within the stream.